# C#: Regex for any number plus a decimal point that does not have a limit

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regex that is capable of validating that a string contains any number from 0 upwards and also allows for a decimal point to be at any position other than something like .1 or .45. By the decimal being at any point I mean the number should be capable of having any number of precision places.

Numbers could really be anything:

```
1
2
3.5
3.58278723475
6523424.82347265
```

I have this which of course fails as my regex doesnt take decimal points into account:

```
 foreach (string[] coorPairArray in extents.Select(t => t.Trim().Split(' ')))
 {
     Regex isnumber = new Regex("^[0-9]+$");

     if ((!isnumber.IsMatch(coorPairArray[0]) || (!isnumber.IsMatch(coorPairArray[1]))))
     {
         dataBaseConnection.Close();

         throw new ArgumentException("Error: An extent value contained alphanumeric data. GetExtentsAsGml().");
     }
  }
```

Comment: Minor point: I would move the "isNumber" initialisation outside the foreach loop (or even to a static field): no need to re-initialize it on every run through the loop. Saves a few microseconds :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
 Regex isnumber = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$");
```

Comment: this will allow 001 as valid.

Comment: You are right, better solution is `^[1-9]*([1-9]|0)?(\.[0-9]+)?$`

Answer (score 3):

Do you even need a regex for this? Wouldn't something like this work:

```
foreach (string[] coorPairArray in extents.Select(t => t.Trim().Split(' '))) 
{
    var lat = Decimal.MinValue;
    var lng = Decimal.MinValue;
    if (!Decimal.TryParse(coorPairArray[0], out lat) || !Decimal.TryParse(coorPairArray[1], out lng))
    {
         dataBaseConnection.Close(); 
         throw new ArgumentException("Error: An extent value contained alphanumeric data. GetExtentsAsGml().");
    }

    // do something with lat/lng
}
```

Comment: Maybe but I was still interested to see what the regex was. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

```
[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)? | 0\.[0-9]+
```

First one is for normal numbers.
Second one to handle things like 0.1

Of course add ^ and $ as required.

I would rather go with James' answer instead of this. it is only for curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Better to do a tryparse as in @James answer, if you want to go throught the regex then here is a sample :

```
[Test]
[TestCase("1")]
[TestCase("2")]
[TestCase("3.5")]
[TestCase("3.58278723475")]
[TestCase("6523424.82347265")]
public void FluentCalculator_Test(string testSource)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(testSource, @"^(?:[-+]?[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?$");
    Assert.IsTrue(match.Success);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why it is better to do the tryParse rather than the regex? In my code the try parse doesnt really fit in well so I will stick with the regex for now but what are the reasons for favouring a tryparse? +1 for the useful unit test btw :)

Comment: @CSharpened `TryParse` is built into the Framework therefore will not break in future versions of .NET (unless of course they change the `TryParse` method which is highly unlikely). Also IMO you are sort of misusing regex in this scenario. Your not trying to *match* data, your trying to validate it so actually try parse is a *better fit*. If your worried about what the code looks like then why not just introduce a helper method e.g. `ValidateCoordinates` and then you abstract the validation logic which gives you the flexibility of changing it without affecting your business logic.

Comment: Thats actually a very good idea and some good reasons too James. Thanks. In terms of the actual regex I will have to keep Mennans answer as the correct one as it answered my question. Thinking about it now though I will abstract out the functionality as you mentioned. Dont know why I didnt think about that as I have done similar elsewhere in the solution.

Comment: Also, here you can find some info about regex vs tryparse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715200/regex-vs-tryparse-what-is-the-best-in-performance

Answer (score 0):

this works with me fine

```
    @"^\d*(?:\.\d+)?$"
```